# Slow sql query - over 15000ms - simple SELECT query, CPU over 100%

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have page with simple sql queries:

Visitor is on page 940 so I need to find products to show on this page:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE stock = 1 AND hide = 0 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 36 
OFFSET 33804
```

this query takes `15463.242 ms`.

Also I need to show filter with manufacturers, sizes and store info for all products in stock:

```
SELECT MANUFACTURER, sizes, store 
FROM items 
WHERE stock = 1 AND hide = 0
```

this takes `17996.684 ms`.

I don't understand why it takes so much time.

Structure of table:

```
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
ID_PRODUCT  varchar(200)     
PRODUCT varchar(200)     
DESCRIPTION mediumtext   
URL varchar(300)     
PRICE_VAT   int(7)   
MANUFACTURER    varchar(150)     
CATEGORY    varchar(150)     
IMGSURL varchar(3000)    
catids  varchar(30)  
sizes   varchar(30)  
store   varchar(30)  
stock   int(1)   
hide    int(1)
```

Table info:

```
Data size: 327 974 912
Index size: 12 075 008
Free space: 4 194 304
Rows: 310 823
```

It uses InnoDB and mysql 5.5.5-10.0.29-MariaDB-0+deb8u1.

Can you please help me what is wrong with this queries? Visitors can't wait over 30 seconds. Also the CPU is more than 100% while doing hte query.

Comment: What is index of your tables? 300k rows seem not too much

Comment: Do you have indexes?

Comment: Thank you for reply. 

Yes, I have indexes. PRIMARY is id and INDEX is ID_PRODUCT. I don't know if it this correct. id is unique auto increment int value and ID_PRODUCT is unique for combination with store. (when I update database, I have to find products with 'select * from items where id_product = ? and store = ?')

Comment: Create index for your `stock` and `hide` field and try to query again

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it's faster. First query takes 4253.172 ms and second one 3876.506 ms. I would make it more faster anyway.

Comment: it's known that MySQL performance is bad when you use a large offset number within limit.. MySQL needs the save 33804 + 36 = 33840 records in memory.. If you use EXPLAIN you will see MySQL probably uses a "using filesort  using temporary table" for this query that combination is a real performance killer within MySQL... The most optimal index for this query is `items(stock, hide, id)`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, it uses filesort. Is there any faster alternative to filesort or how are large websites sorting their data?

Comment: @JackDavis - Your last comment makes "assumptions that are not in evidence".  An `INDEX` has things pre-sorted; Raymond's index provides that trick.  Large websites avoid sorting.  One way is indicated in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tough.

How did the user get to page 940?  Certainly not by clicking [Next] 939 times?  Or maybe it is a Google robot?

What type of data is worth paginating to that degree?  I would find some other way to structure the data that does not involve more than a few hundred items per level of a hierarchical tree, for example.  If each level had exactly 36 items, the tree would be only 4 levels deep for 310K rows.  3 clicks is better than 939.  *And* the underlying query will be faster.  Even a straight-forward 2-level hierarchy of store+product would help a lot.

OK.  I'll give you a few clues of what can be done.

First. Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; you have left out a bunch of useful info.

- Is `ID_PRODUCT` unique?  If it is, perhaps it should be the `PRIMARY KEY`?  A comment implies that `PRIMARY KEY(id_product, store)` (in either order) would be beneficial.
- `INDEX(stock, hide)` (in either order) may help performance.
- `INDEX(stock, hide, id)`, plus changing the pagination to "remember where you left off" would make the pagination immensely faster.  Further discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).
- What's the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size?
- 100% CPU implies that you are not I/O-bound, and we need to focus on indexes and query formulation.  (A hardware upgrade is not useful -- all CPUs today are about the same speed.)
- You say `ORDER BY id DESC`; is that necessary?  Or would some other order be OK?  Note that page 940 probably contains a mixture of products from a mixture of stores.
- Did you know that "pagination via offset and limit" is prone to skipping and/or duplicating items in the output?